# How do I reverse a git submodule so that all folders are pointing at the same git repo?

Tags: git, github

When I created a git repo for an existing project, I accidentally committed and pushed a folder within the project as submodule. How can I change it so that it joins the parent repo? I want to be able to add, commit and push in all the folders/files at the root of the project and not have them separated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follow:

```
git mv git_folder2/submodule/* git_folder/.
git rm git_folder2/submodule
git add .
git commit -m "move submodule one folder-level back"
```

#### Before:

```
|-- git_folder1
|-- git_folder2
    |-- submodule
|-- git_folder3
```

#### After:

```
|-- git_folder1
|-- git_folder2
|-- submodule
|-- git_folder3
```